# Redirect an entire site with .htaccess but exclude sitemap.xml and robots.txt

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, router

Hey Stack Overflowers.

I created a blog using php, mysql and php router concept.

All request going to index.php there I am dynamically get data from database then showing to them.

My problem is all request are going to index.php but i need to redirect except **sitemap**, **robots** & **/admin** folder

My folder structure:

```
-example.com
 -admin
 -assets
 -function
 -views
.htaccess
index.php
config.php
sitemap.php
robots.txt
```

My htaccess code:

```
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just below `RewriteEngine on` line, you can add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:sitemap\.php|robots\.txt|admin/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```